# htaccess: rewrite first "&" with "?" is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^add_link/(.*)$                 ./add_link.php?$1
RewriteRule ^add_link/(.*)?(.*)$            ./add_link.php?$1&$2
```

When the URL is `/add_link/123123?link_id=1` I can't get the "link_id", I only get it when I use `/add_link/123123&link_id=1`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the query string (the part after the question mark `?`) is matched in a separate `QUERY_STRING` variable. Also you can append to the query string using the `[QSA]` flag. So you just need to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^add_link/(.*)$ /add_link.php?$1 [QSA]
```

If you did want to match and capture the query string, you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ...
```

Using `%1` in your `RewriteRule` substitution to get the capture from the `RewriteCond`. But if you just want the whole query string then you don't need to do that as you can use `%{QUERY_STRING}` in your substitution. But `[QSA]` will just append to the query string when you specify one in your substitution, so that should suit your needs in this case as shown above.

`/add_link/123123&link_id=1` works for you because it doesn't have a query string `?`, the `&` is just part of the URL in that case.